# virtualbox guest system broken after installing virtualbox-guest-x11

Tags: virtualbox, xubuntu, xorg

After I installed the package `virtualbox-guest-x11` on my guest system (Xubuntu 17.10) and do a reboot, I cant use it anymore. The reboot works, but when the desktop appears I first get errors that `whiskey menu` and another item from the taskbar I don't remember disappeared from the menubar.

They cant be reactivated and it is also impossible to open any other tool. I can click everything and use the keyboard, the GUI reacts but no App will start. No filemanager and not even the terminal.

Comment: See [my answer here](https://askubuntu.com/a/22745/3940) on how to remove the guest additions. Guest additions should match the virtualbox version you are using.

Comment: thats not the actual problem, I did a snapshot before installing so I can restore the system. But how can I install x11 then? Need it to get the clipboard working

Comment: You can follow the instructions starting at "Installing Guest Additions from Virtual Box Manager".

Comment: Same problem here. Installing vitualbox-guestadditions-x11 is the only way I found for sharing clipboard but it breaks mouse and keyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was here again, that I tried to install the guest settings from an older kernel system (Xubuntu 16.04 as host) in a newer kernel system (xubuntu 17.10(